# SSL_connect gives error SSL_ERROR_SSL after 0.9.8.y to 0.9.8.zb upgrade

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, upgrade

My application works fine when fresh install with openssl 0.9.8.y 
It works fine when fresh install with openssl 0.9.8.zb

But when I upgrade application from openssl 0.9.8.y to openssl 0.9.8.zb, it fails; SSL_connect fails and gives error SSL_ERROR_SSL.

Anyone has any idea why this behavior? Anyone faced similar problems?

Comment: after adding more debug logs I found ERR_error_string_n() gives error "error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For same input, output of X509_NAME_hash is different in 0.9.8y and 0.9.8zb.
This was the root cause.